# Are there any resources for learning korean specifically for people specializing in programming and 3D design?

Tags: resources

I wanna work in the Korean game industry, are there any resources out there that specifically teach the korean language for programming jobs or people doing 3D assets for games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter, Google the following and browse through the promising pages.

프로그래밍 기초 용어

게임 프로그래밍 용어

3D 프로그래밍 용어

The bigger challenge may be the casual conversational Korean.